# Is `import std;` a realistic goal for a C++ project with transitive standard library `#include`s?

Tags: c++, c++-modules

Visual Studio 2022 17.5 and later supports importing the C++23 standard library named module `std` by replacing all instances of `#include <header>` with `import std;` where `<header>` is a standard library header.

According to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170) there are some limitations, such as the following:

> Don't mix and match importing C++ standard library header files and named modules. For example, don't #include <vector> and import std; in the same file.

Does this mean that if I use `import std;` in a file (by "file" I assume that the tutorial is referring to a `.cpp` file or other translation unit), then none of the non-standard library headers that it `#include`s is allowed to transitively `#include` a standard library header?

I'm pretty sure the answer is obviously yes, because after preprocessing, it doesn't really matter whether an `#include` is transitive or not - its contents will end up in the `.cpp` file mixed with the `import` statement.

But then what can be done to prevent mixing besides an exhaustive search of all transitive `#include`s to see if there are any standard library headers? Especially if a project depends on something like Boost, it doesn't seem that `import std;` will be a realistic option until Boost is itself available as a module, right?

So in the meantime, am I right that `import std;` is basically only realistic for new or small projects where the standard library header dependencies (both direct and transitive) can be fully tracked and migrated at the same time? Or is there a way to somehow migrate a project to `import std;` even if some of its dependencies have not yet migrated?

If I compile the following code with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.37.32824 for x64 then I get C2572, which indeed suggests that transitive `#include`s cannot be mixed with `import std;`.

header.hpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "header.hpp"
import std;
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

```
C:\Code\import-std-test>cl /std:c++latest /EHsc /nologo /W4 /MTd "%VCToolsInstallDir%\modules\std.ixx" main.cpp
std.ixx
main.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\xtr1common(42): error C2572: 'std::enable_if': redefinition of default argument: parameter 1
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\xtr1common(43): note: see declaration of 'std::enable_if'
main.cpp(5): fatal error C1117: unrecoverable error importing module 'std': symbol 'byte' has already been defined
Generating Code...
```

Comment: The limitation is specific to the current compiler. It is *supposed* to work, but not yet fully implemented. (Just a guess, but the fact that modules hide macros, makes supporting include guards tricky).

Comment: Interesting topic. I wonder how to address issue where third party library was not ported yet to modules and we like to use it code where modules are used. Does it mean that  we can't do `import std;` and `#include <someLib.h>` if this library does `#include <string>` in its header files? Can this issue be addressed somehow? For example create new module which will expose this third party library as module?

Comment: @BoP Could you share where you saw or heard that this limitation is specific to the current compiler? Do you have a link to an issue where the full implementation is being tracked?

Comment: It's from a talk by mr STL himself https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dk_C_E8AtRs&t=1990s The second point on the slide says "the compiler doesn't handle this yet."

Comment: @BoP Aha, there it is, thanks for the link! So it would seem that `import std;` will be a realistic goal after all once this is fully implemented according to the standard.

Comment: I didn't know MSVC module implementation was not standard. I observed this behavior already and managed to port some of our C++ code base to use `import std;` instead of using `#include`. For me, the limitation seems very logical, I cannot imagine how a compiler could possibly implement mixing module and `#import` for the same header. I would bet that this is unfixable, but let's see how it will evolve in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @BoP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77220989/is-import-std-a-realistic-goal-for-a-c-project-with-transitive-standard-lib#comment136147907_77220989) it's now clear that mixing `import std;` and `#include <header>` is supposed to work but simply hasn't been implemented yet in MSVC (a fact that unfortunately is not mentioned in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170)). The linked talk doesn't mention when it will be available, but it sounds like Microsoft is actively working on it.

So to answer the original question: no, `import std;` is not a realistic goal at the moment for most projects, but yes, it will be when MSVC fully implements the standard, which allows for mixing the two.

Comment: *"doesn't mention when it will be available"*  Employees of large corporations will never be allowed to give preliminary dates, because if the release is delayed some idiot will sue for a billion dollars.  :-)

Comment: @sweemer - The MS documentation/tutorial referenced does specify now that `import std;` and `#include` of C++ header files is not currently supported.